# How to identify an Excel cell that contains local language characters, such as Thai, Chinese, Japanese?

Tags: microsoft-excel, language, auto-detect

I have a long list of addresses which contains letters, numbers, special characters and some local language characters. Is there a way that able to identify those cell that contain local language character?

Sample:

> 65/1 Muban สำโรง Moo 6

Comment: google docs has a [`DETECTLANGUAGE` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093278?hl=en). Unfortunately there's nothing like that in Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Separate string so that there is only 1 character in each cell (e.g. if `A1` is "cat" it should be separated out to `B1:c` `C1:a` `D1:t`)
2. Get the unicode value for each character (e.g. `=unicode(B1)`, etc.)
3. Create a lookup function that links to another table (that you will need to create) that indicates which unicode characters link to which local languages. Determine which ones you find acceptable for your purpose.